# Error using save( ) in Laravel command

Tags: laravel-4

I am setting up my first Laravel command, but having an issue saving the the record.

My model:

```
Public static function contractorDecline(){
    return DB::table('job_interviews')
        ->where('job_interviews.status', '=', 'awaiting contractor response')
        ->get();
}
```

I set up a command to change the status after 24 hours with no action:

```
public function fire()
{
    //
    $tooLate = Carbon::Now()->subHours(24);
    $interviews = JobInterview::contractorDecline();
    //

    foreach($interviews as $interview){
        if ($interview->response_received_on <= $tooLate){
            $interview->status = 'contractor declined interview';
            $interview->save();
        } 
    }
    return('finished');
}
```

When I run the command, I am getting the error:

```
"Call to undefined method stdClass::save()"
```

What do I need to add to the controller to be able to use save() in the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Fluent which returns a simple object and calling Eloquent `save` method on it. If you want to update the row you should use Eloquent instead. Assuming you have a `JobInterview` class(*Model*) for the `job_interviews` table, you can code:

```
JobInterview::whereStatus('awaiting contractor response')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I didn't realize that I couldn't mix the two.